# formula from the path to another file from the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a lot of formulas referencing other files and it's bothering me to manually change the cell on the file path cell. He tries to connect cells, but he gives me pure text without a formula. I remember that on Excel 2010 it worked, but for 2013 I have a problem. Below is an example

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem but if you mean that you need to change all the links from one workbook to another then try Data - Edit Links (from connections section).  In the popup dialog you can 'change source' for the links.

Comment: Look into INDIRECT, but it will require the other workbook to be open when to bring in the values.

Answer (score 0):

try formula "address". It helps to construct path to the needed cell within other workbook.